# iOS Symbolication without App file

Tags: ios

Several companies (Crittercism, Crashlytics, Hockeyapp and others) offer crash symbolication services for iOS. These require one to upload your apps dSYM file/folder but they don't ask you to upload the associated App file.

Symbolicatecrash, ATOS and related tools all seem to require both the APP and dSYM files to symbolicate a crash. How do they get around this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The app binary is not used or required for the actual symbolication process. The symbolicatecrash script from Xcode is requiring the app binary to be available but actually never uses it. It is not documented why the script requires the binary to be available though. You can verify this yourself by opening the script (it is written in Perl) in an editor.

Comment: Using -v in symblociatecrash I see atos being used like this: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/atos -arch arm64 -l 0x1000dc000 -o '/working/MyTest.app/MyTest' 0x0000000100147f8c 0x1000E7EF3. This appears to use the app and not the dSYM

Comment: If you don't call the script providing the app package as an option, it will use Spotlight to search the dSYM and then use that. And even if it uses the app binary, you will not get filename or line number information which means the result is pretty useless overall anyway. But anyway, the answer to your question is still the same. The app binary is not needed and even if used requires the symbols not to be stripped (30-50% app size increase) and even then won't provide that much information compared to using the dSYM alone.

Comment: I agree the dSYM contains the best info. But symbolicatecrash script skips symbolication (for my binary) with dSYM present unless the associated app is also available. I want to remove the app dependency from the script.

Comment: It appears symbolicatecrash requires the app binary to determine the 'slide' so it can adjust the crashlog addresses before feeding to the dSYM. So how does HockeyApp/Crittercism etc get away with not supplying the app?